# How to boot a Hyper-V Virtual Machine with a PXE server

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, pxe-boot

I am trying to boot a virtual machine created in Hyper-V Manager. I want to boot from the NIC so that the VM can connect to the PXE server (by pressing F12 numerous times). The thing is, I cannot get to boot at all. All I get is the classic: "Boot failure. Reboot and Select proper Boot device..."

Here are my settings for this VM:

```
Hardware
  BIOS
    1st boot device: Legacy Network adapter
  Network Adapter
    Network: Local Area Connection - Virtual Network
    MAC Address: Dynamic, 00-15-5D-4C-1A-02
```

This machine is already added in the System Center Config Manager on the PXE server... But at this point this is irrevelant because the machine is not even booting!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hyper-V supports booting a Virtual Machine from the network using the F12 option. The trick is that you must use the Legacy Network Adapter.  The regular network adapter is synthetic is not available at boot time. You have to remove the existing network adapter and add a new Legacy Network Adapter.

Comment: Just a weird little item, but MS Natural Ergonomic Keyboards often do not send the F12 command to a vm you are trying to PXE. In the case of a vm that has not been imaged yet, you may get this same error message because it ends up skipping network boot and looks for an operating system which is not there yet. If you have an ergo keyboard, instead, connect a traditional rectangular usb keyboard and F12 should work fine.

Comment: For me Hyper-V wasn't properly configured for the virtual machine to connect to the internet, so these instructions were helpful: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2087-hyper-v-virtualization-setup-use-windows-10-a.html (After enabling Hyper-V, create a virtual switch, and then create the vm)